# How to add a text inside a circle in Mapbox Gl Js

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I want to add a Text inside a circle, which is my marker, but it doesnt show anything.

I have two layers, one for the circles and one for the text.

I am trying to get it to work by adding a text-field property, but nothigs gets rendered.

This are my two layers, the one where im trying to add the text is the second one called singles-count

```
      map.addLayer({
        id: "singles",
        // type: "symbol",
         type: "circle",
        source: "users",
        filter: ["!has", "point_count"],
        // layout: { 
        //   "icon-image": "custom-marker"
        // },
        paint: {
            'circle-radius': {
                'base': 10,
                'stops': [[5, 20], [15, 500]]
            },
            'circle-color': '#ddffc8',
          }
      });
    });


    map.addLayer({
        id: "singles-count",
        type: "symbol",
        source: "users",
        filter: ["has", "singles_count"],
        layout: {
        "text-field": "XXX",
        "text-font": ["DIN Offc Pro Medium", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
        "text-size": 12
        }
      });
```

But, it doesnt render the XXX nor throws any error, Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 possible things that could go wrong here:

- `filter: ["has", "singles_count"]` results in `false` for each
  feature and no symbols are being rendered because of that.
- It seems
  like you have a pretty big circle radius `'stops': [[5, 20], [15, 500]]`. It is possible that the `singles` layer overlaps `singles-count` layer completely and the text is actually being rendered but it is **under** the circle. To fix this you need to specify `beforeId` parameter of `addLayer` function like [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addlayer):

```
map.addLayer({
        id: "singles-count",
        type: "symbol",
        source: "users",
        filter: ["has", "singles_count"],
        layout: {
        "text-field": "XXX",
        "text-font": ["DIN Offc Pro Medium", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
        "text-size": 12
}, 'singles');
```

- The font glyphs for `["DIN Offc Pro Medium", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"]` can not be found on your map tiles hosting servier. (`404` error in networks tab)

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a test case with jsfiddle/codepen? Layers look right but filters might be filtering out all data.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party  but:

1. `AddLayer` needs a value for `SourceLayer` if it is a vector layer
2. The `text-field` property needs to be an actual property of the feautures on the `Source` & `SourceLayer`